# Cheap() && Expensive()

Tags: optimization

This comment was made on a question i asked about optimisation. "Note that cheap() && expensive() is not an optimisation of expensive () && cheap() in a language with short-circuit evaluation unless you can guarantee that both expensive() and cheap() are side effect free"

**what does this mean?**

Comment: Is this a comment to a question you already asked?

Comment: I would think that "Cheap" effectively implies side-effect free.  Unfortunately, this is opinion, and speculation on opinion about which there is no definitive answer, and will probably get closed (*edit:* or maybe not!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to short circuit evaluation, when the expression `expensive () && cheap()` runs, `cheap()` will only run if `expensive()` returns true. In the case where both methods are side effect free, which means they are just returning a boolean and **not** making any changes application state, then the expressions can be reversed to `cheap() && expensive()`, which will be faster assuming `cheap()` is not always true.

However, in the case where either method modifies the state of the application then the reversed expression may not be functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

If cheap() and/or expensive() can have side effects, then in a language with short-circuiting AND, changing the order can change the semantics of the program, I.e., you get a different answer just by changing the order.